# Do the calculation in vapor4

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm trying to solve the return type `Bool` to `Pers` in the func calculation. And the main thing i want to do is that giving a longitude and a latitude to return a "In range" `Pers` model.(not return a distance) And should i use a post or a get method.
if I use a `postgis`. How do i actually make the longitude and latitude i type in into `GeometricPoint2D`. There is no field for me to save a `GeometricPoint2D` type because i don't really know that how to get or post a request with that type.

Controller:

```
import Foundation
import Vapor
import Fluent

final class InformationController{

    func radian(d:Double) -> Double {
        return d * Double.pi/180.0
    }

    func getDistance(lat1:Double,lng1:Double,lat2:Double,lng2:Double) -> Double {
        let EARTH_RADIUS:Double = 6378137.0

        let radLat1:Double = self.radian(d: lat1)
        let radLat2:Double = self.radian(d: lat2)

        let radLng1:Double = self.radian(d: lng1)
        let radLng2:Double = self.radian(d: lng2)

        let a:Double = radLat1 - radLat2
        let b:Double = radLng1 - radLng2

        var s:Double = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin(a/2), 2) + cos(radLat1) * cos(radLat2) * pow(sin(b/2), 2)))
        s = s * EARTHRADIUS
        return s
    }

    func calculate2 ( req:Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[Pers]> {
        let userlocation = try req.content.decode(Pers.self)
        return Pers.query(on: req.db).all().map{ user in
            user.map{
                let distance = self.getDistance(lat1: $0.latitude, lng1: $0.longitude, lat2: userlocation.latitude, lng2: userlocation.longitude) < 100
                return //Pers
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
import Foundation
import Fluent
import Vapor
import FluentPostgresDriver


final class Pers:Model,Content{
    static let schema = "people"

    @ID(key: .id)
    var id:UUID?

    @Field(key: "姓名")
    var name: String

    @Field(key: "IG帳號")
    var account: String

    @Field(key: "頭像")
    var picture: String

    @Field(key: "年紀")
    var age: String

    @Field(key: "生日")
    var birth: String

    @Field(key:"緯度")
    var latitude: Double

    @Field(key:"經度")
    var longitude: Double

    @Field(key: "居住城市")
    var city: String

    @Field(key: "興趣")
    var hobby : String

    @Parent(key: "user_id")
    var user: User

    init(){}

    init(id:UUID?=nil, name:String, account:String, picture:String ,age:String, birth:String,latitude: Double, longitude: Double, city:String, hobby:String, userId:UUID){
        self.id=id
        self.name=name
        self.account=account
        self.picture=picture
        self.age=age
        self.birth=birth
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.city=city
        self.hobby=hobby
        self.$user.id=userId
    }
}
```

if I use `postgis`. How do I convert the longitude and latitude I type to `GeometricPoint2D`.

```
func gis (_ req:Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[Pers]> {
        let userlocation = try req.content.decode(Pers.self)
        let searchLocation = GeometricPoint2D(x: userlocation.longitude, y: userlocation.latitude)
        let Per.query(on: req.db).filterGeometryDistanceWithin(.$location, searchLocation, 1000).all()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your DB model so the latitude and longitude are stored as a `GeometricPoint2D` in the DB instead of separate fields. That will then let the `filterGeometryDistanceWithin` query work